# Como hacer un repeater en wordpress con una fila de dos columnas y otra de tres

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola estoy queriendo realizar un repeater en wordpress pero me surgio un problema con el diagramado hecho en bootstrap. adjunto una imagen de dicho ejemplo[image: ejemplo de como seria]
el codigo que yo implemente es el siguiente: 
Si bien yo arme un repeater lo que me hace es repetir las columnas en col-lg-6

Como podría resolverlo?
haciendo algún tipo de contador?

```html
   <section class="container services">
    <div class="row text-center animated fadeInUp notransition">
                 <?php if(have_rows('proceso_de_consultoria')):
                     while(have_rows('proceso_de_consultoria')): the_row();?>  
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <i class="<?php the_sub_field('icono_consultoria'); ?> "></i>
        <?php the_sub_field('descripcion_de_los_pasos'); ?>
       </div>
                  <?php endwhile;
                 endif;?>
                 <!-- <div class="col-md-6">
      <i class=" icon-eye-open"></i>
      <h4>EVALUACIÓN</h4>
      <p>Evaluación, diagnóstico y certificación de programadores.</p>
     </div> -->
    </div>

     <!--  <div class="row text-center topspace30 animated fadeInDown notransition">
   
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <i class="icon-file-text"></i>
      <h4>MARCOS (Radan)</h4>
      <p>Escritura de macros de personalización de su sistema (sólo Radan).</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <i class="icon-thumbs-up-alt"></i>
      <h4>INTEGRACIÓN</h4>
      <p>Integración MRP / ERP</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <i class="icon-gear"></i>
      <h4>POST PROCESADORES<br />(Radan / Edgecam)</h4>
      <p>Escritura de Post Procesadores a medida</p>
     </div>
    </div> -->

   </section>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No se si se logro comprender lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, entiendo que quieres montar esta estructura `HTML` iterando en los post consultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También entiendo que según lo que comentas, siempre vas a mostrar 5 resultados distribuidos del siguiente modo:

1. En la primero fila se mostrarán en dos columnas los dos primeros
   resultados
2. En la segunda fila los tres restantes

Se podría resolver con un contador que controle el número de post en el que se encuentra el bucle y asignando la clase en función de ello.

En este caso concreto, la primera fila siempre tendrá dos columnas y todas las siguientes tendrán tres.

Aquí tienes el código con los cambio comentados:

```
    <section class="container services">
      <div class="row text-center animated fadeInUp notransition">
        <?php if (have_rows('proceso_de_consultoria')):

            //Variable contador que contará el número de post mostrado
            $i=0;

            while (have_rows('proceso_de_consultoria')): the_row(); 

            //aquí definimos la clase en función del post en el que nos encontramos
            $i<2 ? $class="col-md-6" : $class="col-md-4";

                  //imprimimos la clase ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class ?>>

                    <i class="<?php the_sub_field('icono_consultoria'); ?> "></i>
                    <?php the_sub_field('descripcion_de_los_pasos'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php 

            // incrementamos el valor del contador
             $i++;

            endwhile;
        endif; ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <i class=" icon-eye-open"></i>
            <h4>EVALUACIÓN</h4>
            <p>Evaluación, diagnóstico y certificación de programadores.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ernesto por la explicación y por la ayuda que me has dado.

Comment: De nada @ElectricMarian espero que te haya servido. ;)